# How can we set query result to http body

Tags: apex, integration, callout, httprequest

```
public Class GenerateCSV {
    public GenerateCSV(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    }

    public List<batch__c> getcontact() {
          return [select Id,Name,Quote_line_item__c from batch__c LIMIT 20];
    }
    String endPoint = 'http://tejdeep.989';
public void postDataToRemote(String name,String email,Integer age){
   performAction('POST',name,email,age);   
}
public void performAction(String method){
      query q=[select Id,Name,Quote_line_item__c from batch__c LIMIT 20];        
             //Prepare http req
             HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
             req.setEndpoint(endPoint);
            req.setMethod(method);
              //query q=[select Id,Name,Quote_line_item__c from batch__c LIMIT 20];
                String JSONString = JSON.serialize(q);   
       
            
            req.setBody(JSONString);
           
            Http http = new Http();
            HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
           
            System.debug(res.getBody());
       
  }
}
```

how can i able to set the query result to http: set body

Answer (score 1):

The call you are using - [HttpRequest.setBody](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_restful_http_httprequest.htm#apex_System_HttpRequest_setBody) - should work:

```
Batch__c[] batches = [select Id,Name,Quote_line_item__c from batch__c LIMIT 20];
req.setBody(JSON.serialize(batches));
```